# Getting data on the right format in react and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hash

I'm trying to make a wordCloud in react javascript, but having some difficulties getting the data on the right format. The data should look like this:

```
<KeywordCloud data={[
    {
      text: 'Pick',
      value: 20,
      font: 'impact',
      …
    },
    {
      text: 'Hello',
      value: 40,
      font: 'impact',
      …
    },
    {
      text: 'Package',
      value: 80,
      font: 'impact',
      …
    },
    …
  ]} />
```

.. but I have all the text I wan't to use in a list

```
let books = [...this.props.searchResult];
book.title
```

how can I get it to be on the right format? When I try to use books.map(book =>, it creates a different wordCloud for each book..

Comment: can you share with us the book format ?

Comment: What do you have in `this.props.searchResult `?

Comment: please share your trial code and the output you require

Comment: The book comes form the database and has values like book.author, book.title etc. I just want it to be for each book: {text: book.title value: Math.random(), font: 'impact'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you push the data to the list, it re-render the app try to separate the return and the logic in the render function, something like this

```
  let data = [];
    let books = [...this.props.searchResult]; // The search result (books)
    books.map(book => data.push({ 
        text: book.title, 
        value: book.value, 
        font: book.font
    }))
    return (
        <div>
          <KeywordCloud data={data} />>
        </div>
    );
```